# Remove/hide original dragged after start drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How can I hide the original draggable element once I start drag?

I tried the `transform:translateX(-9999px);` method but it acts like `visibility: hidden;` and I need something like `display: none;` so in the place where original draggable element was will be populated by other element.

What I've tried:

```
    function dragStart(e) {

        setTimeout(function(){
            e.target.classList.add('block-hide');
        },0);

    }

    function dragOver(e) {

    }
    function dragEnd(e) {

        e.target.classList.remove('block-hide');
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xkcvpf10/1/

Please resize the preview window in order to see 2 blocks in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your class .block-hide to

```
.block-hide{
    display:none;
}
```

seems to do the trick

https://jsfiddle.net/xkcvpf10/2/ (tested in chrome)